# Any way to set request headers when doing a request using urllib in Python 2.x?

Tags: python, http, urllib, python-2.6, python-2.x

I am trying to make an HTTP request in Python 2.6.4, using the urllib module. Is there any way to set the request headers?

I am sure that this is possible using urllib2, but I would prefer to use urllib since it seems simpler.

Comment: Thank you all. I'll just use urllib2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so, but *urllib2* can. Check out the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) of *urllib2.Request*.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any way to do that, which is precisely the reason `urllib` is deprecated in favour of `urllib2`.  So just use `urllib2` rather than writing new code to a deprecated interface.

Answer (score 1):

You could actually overwrite methods in `FancyURLopener`, but that does not seem right (see http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib._urlopener). You could also use `httplib` which basically is the backend for `urllib`.

But anyhow, using `urllib2` might be the best idea. It is not difficult to use. (I use it all the time.)